# how to search from comma separated column value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a search string 
$searchStr = 'anti'
and have table mytable

- id      name            keywords
- 1       Avast           antivirus,virus protection,alert
- 2       Norton         norton,antivirus
- 3       Kesper        antivirus,virus,kesper
- 4       php                php,mysql,code

i want to fetch data according to Keywords
like if i search "anti"
it fetch results with id 1,2,3

Comment: where `Keywords` like '%anti%'

Comment: Use a real search engine instead, you will have a terrible performance otherwise.

Comment: the first comment is your answer, now you just need to build the SQL in front of it. Give it a try and come back with your code if it is not working.

Comment: like doesnt work becoz column keywords have comma seperated values

Comment: i used FIND_IN_SET but it also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from table WHERE Keywords like '%anti%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mysqli` :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE find_in_set(?, myField) <> 0');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchStr);
$stmt->execute();
```

Use the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Comment: like doesnt work becoz column keywords have comma seperated values
i used FIND_IN_SET but it also doesnt work

Comment: Ok, perhaps with my new code (I edited my answer), but you said FIND_IN_SET doesn't work, strange :/